# How to add/install cypress in dockerimage

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cypress

How to add/install cypress in my docker base image? This is my baseimage dockerfile file where I am installing common dependencies.
How can I install cypress. I don't want to install it via package.json. I want it to be pre-installed.

```
FROM node:lts-stretch-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl wget gnupg
RUN apt-get install python3-dev -y
RUN curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
RUN python3 get-pip.py
RUN pip3 install awscli --upgrade
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
RUN apt-key update && apt-get update && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
```

Answer (score 0):

There are docker images available with cypress already in them.

CircleCI have one for their CI testing.

> For convenience, CircleCI maintains several Docker images. These
>   images are typically extensions of official Docker images and include
>   tools especially useful for CI/CD. All of these pre-built images are
>   available in the CircleCI org on Docker Hub. Visit the circleci-images
>   GitHub repo for the source code for the CircleCI Docker images. Visit
>   the circleci-dockerfiles GitHub repo for the Dockerfiles for the
>   CircleCI Docker images

https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/?gclid=Cj0KCQiApaXxBRDNARIsAGFdaB9QO4ZaUXxHzyuRWVc19uzIN0Baz5qd5npQb6rHL3wbup6pFLwKb-4aArzOEALw_wcB